# How do I know the password requirements of the VM running my Azure role?

Tags: security, azure, passwords, windows-server-2008-r2

I tried to switch my Azure service from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2008 R2. Now the code that creates a local user fails with

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PasswordException
>   The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements.

Clearly R2 doesn't like the password I assign to the local user.

How do I know what password complexity requirement exactly is violated?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TechNet Article covering the [minimum requirements for password complexity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736605%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) on Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

I just verified on one of my 2008 R2 instances and these policies are active by default:

- Maximum password age: 42 days
- Password must meet complexity requirements

> Password must meet complexity requirements
>
> This security setting determines whether passwords must meet
>   complexity requirements.
>
> If this policy is enabled, passwords must meet the following minimum
>   requirements:
>
> Not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name
>   that exceed two consecutive characters Be at least six characters in
>   length Contain characters from three of the following four categories:
>   English uppercase characters (A through Z) English lowercase
>   characters (a through z) Base 10 digits (0 through 9) Non-alphabetic
>   characters (for example, !, $, #, %) Complexity requirements are
>   enforced when passwords are changed or created.

The password complexity is OK, but the maximum password age could be an issue. You can disable this by modifying it once through RDP, exporting these settings, and then write a startup task that imports those settings. Here are the commands you can use for that:

```
secedit /export /cfg settings.inf
secedit /import /db secedit.sdb /cfg settings.inf
```